# Reformat a column to only first 5 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I'm struggling with this section. There are about 25 columns in a text file and 50,000+ Rows. For one of the columns, #11 (**ZIP**), this column contains all the zip code values of customers in this format "**07598-XXXX**", I would only like to get the first 5, so "**07598**", I need to do this for the entire column but I'm confused based on my current logic how to write it.
So far my code is able to delete rows that contains certain strings and I am also using the '|' delimiter to format it nicely as a CSV.

State   | ZIP(#11) | Column 12| ....

---

NY  | 60169-8547  | 98

NY  | 60169-8973  | 58

NY  | 11219-4598  | 25

NY  | 11219-8475  | 12

NY  | 20036-4879  | 56

How can I iterate through the ZIP column and just show the first 5 characters?
Thanks for the help!

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC-EIM','-INAC','TO-INAC','TO_INAC','SHIP_TO-inac','SHIP_TOINAC']


with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
         writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process title line separately, then read row by row like you do, just modify second `line` column by truncating to 5 characters.

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC-EIM','-INAC','TO-INAC','TO_INAC','SHIP_TO-inac','SHIP_TOINAC']


with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    cr = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
    # iterate over title line and write it as-is
    writer.writerow(next(cr))
    for line in cr:
        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
            line[1] = line[1][:5]   # truncate
            writer.writerow(line)
```

alternately, you could use `line[1] = line[1].split("-")[0]` which would keep everything on the left of the dash character.

Note the special processing for the title line: `cr` is an iterator. I just consume it manually before the `for` loop to perform a pass-through processing.

Comment: This worked perf! Thanks!! Question, how does "writer.writerow(next(cr))" exactly work? I'm a little confused about this part. Especially the cr part inside.

Answer (score 3):

```
'{:.5}'.format(zip_)
```

where `zip_` is the string containing the zip code.  More on `format` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: Please don't use `zip` for the name of the string though. That is a built-in function.

Comment: It is also probably better (more efficient and idiomatic) to slice to get a substring: `'11219-4598'[:5]`

Answer (score 1):

to get first 5 *characters* in a string use `str[:6]`

in your case:

```
with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
            line[1] = line[1][:6]
            writer.writerow(line)
```

`line[1] = line[1][:6]` will set 2nd column in your file to first 5 characters in itself.